# How do I know if I need to update to fix security problems?

Tags: wordpress, upgrade, issues, security, security-advisory

I have recently upgraded to the latest version of CiviCRM and shortly after I received these security warnings

**CiviCRM Security Patch Needed**

> "Fix security issues CIVI-SA-2023-04, -05, and -06."

[image]

Would you like to think that there is no need to update again?
And if so, how can I update for **WordPress**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For clarity, what version are you actually on?

The current version is 5.58.1 which is a security release.  Any version earlier than that will show you need to upgrade.  (Unless you're on ESR)

If you ***are*** on 5.58.1 then those messages are spurious and you don't need to upgrade further at the moment.  Try clearing the cache and running the 'version_check' scheduled job.

Instructions for upgrading in WordPress are here: https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/upgrade/wordpress/

Comment: ♦ I am working on version 5.58.1